# PDF Rendering in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, pdf, pdf.js

How can I render PDF in HTML5 canvas?

I came up with pdf.js script https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js. But its seems this project is still in development.

Comment: Slightly different approach: if you can do your rendering in an in-browser SVG, then either svg2pdf or inkscape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution may be:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html